# Automate forking a github repository

Tags: python, git, github, github-actions, github-api

Here is a script in Python that is used to clone repositories given the github account name (source_account), the name of the source repo (source_repo), and the source branch (source_branch). Is there a way I could change this in order to Fork all public repo's from a User's account given a username?

```
import git
import os
import pandas as pd
import pandasql as ps

# reading csv file of Github_account_details
df = pd.read_csv('github_account_details.csv')

source_accounts = df['source_account'].unique()  # taking all distinct account names

print("****Please select a GitHub account from which you want to clone the Repositories****")

for names in source_accounts:
    print('-->', names)
selected_account = input()  # taking input from user for selecting the particular account

# extracting all the repositories for user's selected account
selected_repo = ps.sqldf(f"select source_repo from df where source_account = '{selected_account}'")
to_clone_repos = []

# making new list with 'source_repo' header
for i in selected_repo.index:
    to_clone_repos.append(selected_repo['source_repo'][i])

total_repos_count = len(to_clone_repos)
print(f"Total repositories in {selected_account} are: {total_repos_count}\n{to_clone_repos}")
permission_to_clone = input("Give permission to Clone Y/N")

# cloning all the repos from to_clone_repos
if permission_to_clone == 'Y' or permission_to_clone == 'Yes' or permission_to_clone == 'YES' or permission_to_clone == 'yes':
    for repos in to_clone_repos:
        if not os.path.exists(selected_account):
            os.makedirs(selected_account)
        print(f"{repos} -- Cloning in Progress")
        git.Git(f'{selected_account}/').clone(f'https://github.com/{selected_account}/{repos}.git')
        print(f"{repos} -- Cloned successfully")
```

Comment: Use the GitHub API for that.

Comment: Depending on the what you're trying to do, the [github  cli](https://cli.github.com/) might be of interest. Forking a repository is as simple as `gh repo fork source_user/source_repo`, and there are commands for getting a list of available repositories. Put the two of those together with a little glue and you probably have what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case (python program), you can use [`sigmavirus24/github3.py`](https://github.com/sigmavirus24/github3.py) which give you access to a wrapper to GitHub CLI.

The [`gh repo fork`](https://cli.github.com/manual/gh_repo_fork) command mentioned in the comments is available through their own API functions.

```py
repository = self.gh.repository("kennethreitz", "requests")
forked_repo = repository.create_fork()
assert isinstance(forked_repo, github3.repos.Repository)

org_forked_repo = repository.create_fork("github3py")
assert isinstance(org_forked_repo, github3.repos.Repository)
```